# Cannot run Minecraft on Windows 7

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-launcher

I started playing Minecraft a few years back but then quit. Now I'm wanting to play it again but whenever I click on the Minecraft Launcher these messages show up:

[image: The first message]

[image: The second message]

Can anyone help please?

I have deleted every single trace of Minecraft from my pc and reinstalled it but it still wouldn’t work.

Comment: Well, **did** you reinstall the game?

Comment: Yes I did delete and reinstall the game but it still won’t work.

Comment: Try uninstalling both Java (every version), Minecraft, and deleting your .minecraft forlder. Then install the latest version of each (not the .minecraft folder) and run the launcher again. Could you also provide us with some of your computer specs? It's possible that Minecraft is unable to run on your computer at all.

Comment: Hi @zach, I tried when you suggested and I did not work, it kept showing the same message . My computer has a AMD FX(tm)-4100 Quad-Core Processor, 3.60 GHz. 8 GB RAM and a 64-Bit OS. I was able to play Minecraft on the same computer years ago but now it is suddenly unplayable.

Comment: @PvPWill when you uninstall minecraft, what is located at the directory listed in the first image? It's kind of difficult to really pinpoint an exact issue; here's a list of some different things that could be a problem:

Comment: 1. You have not been doing a complete uninstall and reinstall of Minecraft and some persistent file is remaining in a place you do not know about.
2. A registry entry is causing Minecraft to launch an invalid file. I don't know if Minecraft adds many registry entries that would cause this issue, however.
3. Your computer is too old and some  of Minecraft's lower level apis no longer are maintained for your computer's type (I highly doubt this is the issue)

Comment: What installer are you using to uninstall Minecraft? Are you using the official one? If so, you might be able to try the repair option when you double click it to see if it will solve your problem.

Comment: @ZachK I’m not sure what you mean by “the directory listed in the first image”. When I use the Minecraft launcher (whether from the Windows Start menu, the taskbar, or from a folder) those 2 messages will pop up.

Comment: I have searched every drive in my pc for anything Minecraft related and deleted/uninstalled them, then I tried downloading the Minecraft launcher from another pc onto a USB then transferring it onto my pc but the same error message still pops up. I am using the official Minecraft launcher but the repair feature won’t work either.

Comment: This problem is starting to be a nuisance. Now most applications won’t open (such as Spotify, Steam, etc) however no error message pops up. They just don’t open.

Answer (score 2):

according to the comments of [this link,](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCL-11754) this is a DNS issue. whatever your network provider/firewall/VPN service is, it's blocking crucial files needed by the Launcher to install. the fix one user used in the aforementioned link is changing your computer's DNS settings to use Google's public DNS server (8.8.8.8).

Comment: According to the same link, the issue could also be due to incompatible software: https://minecraftirc.net/support-articles/known-incompatible-software/